# C++ Pointer Class within Another Class Manipulation

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class called `foo1` and in foo1.h I have

```
class foo1
{
public:
int var;
foo1();
};
```

There is also another class called `foo2`, in which I have an object based on `foo1`:

```
class foo2
{
public:
foo1 *afoo1;
foo2();
void func1(int,int);
};
```

My question is that how I can have access to `afoo1->var`. If I use `afoo1->var` in foo2.cpp, everything looks fine and it compiles with no error. But when I run it in the command prompt window, a window pups up and asks to close the program. I guess this is because I am violating memory access, the cause of which could be `afoo1->var`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

**Extra Note**

I make a dll file from foo2, and use it in another program, the source code of which I do not have any access to. Just to make things clarified a bit more.

**Answer**

I had made two mistakes. The first one was that I was referencing to Null. `afoo1 = new foo1();` in the constructor of `foo2` took care of that.

The second one was that I had not included `foo1.cpp` in my makefile. I know, stupid mistake.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "command window"? C++ is compiled, not interpreted (unlike python for example), so you can't call afoo->var from, say, a shell prompt.

Comment: sorry, I mean command prompt window. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `foo2Instance->afoo1->var`, inside the foo2 methods this will just be `afoo1->var`. If that is crashing it's more likely because you're not initializing `afoo1` in foo2's constructor.

```
#ifndef FOO1_H
#define FOO1_H 

class foo1
{
public:
int var;
foo1() { var = 0; } //make sure the constructor is in fact defined. 
// if it isn't implemented it would cause that linker error.
};

#endif
```

Make sure you have `#include "foo1.h"` in foo2.h

```
   // constructor and deconstructor, these are in the cpp file.
   foo2::foo2()
   {
        afoo1 = new foo1();
   }
   foo2::~foo2()
   {
        delete afoo1;
   }
```

If you're getting a NullReferenceException it's likely because you're missing that line in the constructor. `afoo2->afoo1` is fine when `afoo1 == NULL` however, if you try to access a property of `afoo1` you will crash every time. `NULL->someProperty` is never okay.

Comment: As I added later, I am making a dll file. I guess the first two lines of your code should go somewhere in like main.cpp, which I don't have access to.
Adding the other two lines to constructor and deconstructor causes the following error:
`foo2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public : __thisclass foo1::foo1(void)"`

Comment: You're either missing a reference or need an include guard. I'll edit with resolution.

Comment: I just figured it out! As I was expecting, it was something stupid. I had not included foo1.cpp in my makefile. So, that was it. Plus taking your comment into consideration, my problem is fixed now. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, @ipluto. Thank you for mentioning what you missed. It saved me. I forgot to add my <implementation>.cxx file to CMakeLists.txt . I was building a dll and started to doubt if the declspecs were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> foo2, in which I have an object based on foo1

No, you have a pointer to a foo1. If you haven't set that pointer to actually point to an instance of a foo1 object, then trying to access anything through it will most likely result in a crash. That sounds like what you're experiencing.

So it sounds like either you should make that variable an actual foo1 (example: `foo1 afoo1;`) or you need to set that pointer to point to an instance as suggested by evanmcdonnal (example: `afoo1 = new foo1();`)

Comment: an actual foo1 causes the "unresolved external error", similar to what I mentioned in my comment on evanmcdonnal's answer. This is possible only if I do not want to have a constructor in my class. but as soon as it is defined, everything gets complicated.
afoo1=new foo1(); also gives the same error as I tried it just now.